# Remove specific characters from a string in a cell

Tags: excel, trim

I am trying to have a formula that will have certain characters removed from a string. For Example. CC200-M1-02-1-1 (string) I want this to come out like this, CC200021. So the following characters are removed (-,m,1,-,-,-,1).   I have tried the lens right but this will only remove the last characters. Any suggestions?

CC200-M1-02-1-1

CC230-M1-02-1-1

CC250-M1-02-1-1

CS005-MW-14-1-1

LG100-M0-14-1-1

LG150-M0-14-1-1

LG220-M0-14-1-1

LG230-M0-14-1-1

LX150-M0-14-1-1

Comment: Is the pattern always the same? where you want the first third and forth group?

Comment: @ScottCraner I provided more examples and yes they seem to have the same sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a formula you want then use this:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",REPT(" ",999)),1,999) )&TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",REPT(" ",999)),2*999,999) )&TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",REPT(" ",999)),3*999,999) )
```

[image]

Comment: @Scott, your **`REPT`** function always baffled me.

Comment: @ManishChristian I wish I could take credit for it, but I learned it from tigeravatar and Gary's Student.